# C# JSON POST connect (Method not allowed)

Tags: c#, json

I have problem with connect to JSON server.
In user-manual:

The Interface is implemented as a standard HTTP Service. Using the service requires an authentication through the “Login” method. A Session Id is returned on success which has to be passed on every function call unless otherwise stated.

- The expected data format when sending or receiving data is JSON.
- All data must be passed using POST.
- The session Id is of type Guid

---

Example:

> Login
>
> Description: Used to authenticate a user.
>
> Url: /Login
>
> Signature: Guid Login(string id, string username, string password)
>
> END OF MANUAL

I wrote this code:

```
var webAddr = "https://xxx/Login";
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
                         string json = "{\"Login\":[{"
                         + "\"id\" : 1213213,"
                         + "\"username\" : asdasdasd,"
                         + "\"password\" : \"adasdsadasd\","
                         + "}]}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());

        }
```

And message is: Method not allowed.
How can I send and recive data from this serwer?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that, for simplicity, create a POCO to represent you json type and use the jsonserializer. I always avoid writing json (or xml, for instance) by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are formatting your JSON incorrectly.  The JSON should look like this:

```
{"id":"1213213","username":"asdasdasd","password":"adasdsadasd"}
```

Notice: quotes around each name and value.  And "Login" should not be part of the JSON.

However, the problem is really that you are doing this all manually.  Instead, let .NET format the JSON for you and handle the HTTP request.  To do this, create a structure for the arguments:

```
class Login
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Use NuGet to add references to "Json.Net" and "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries."  Now you can write this:

```
static async Task Login()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.censored.de/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

        Login l = new Login() { id = "12345", password = "abcde", username = "safsdfasdf" };
        var sTemp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l); // DEBUG: Just so I can see the JSON

        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/censored/Service.svc/Login", l);
        Guid g;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            g = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Guid>(); // This gives you the GUID
        }

        //DEBUG:
        // var rawResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // Console.WriteLine(response);

    }
}
```

Notice that I used "async" and "await" keywords.  If you are not familiar with calling an async function, you can change the "await" line to this temporarily:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/censored/Service.svc/Login", l).Result;
```

This results in a 400 Bad Request with this message.

```
{"ErrorMessage":"Die Anmeldedaten sind ungültig.","StackTrace":null}
```

Which Google tells me means that the credentials are wrong.  I assume that is the response one would expect with this user/password combination.